# Is unique index mandatory for partitioning MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, database, partitioning

I would like to add a partition (to part by year 2020, 2021, 2022, etc.) on the table "cns_dvc":

```
+-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id_dvc                | bigint(20)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| dvc                   | varchar(50)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| zone                  | varchar(10)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date_str              | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date_prs              | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| external_id           | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| no_week               | int(6)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| day                   | varchar(30)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| pg_avg                | decimal(6,3)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| i_spd_avg             | decimal(15,3) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| o_spd_avg             | decimal(15,3) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| year                  | int(4)        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| month                 | tinyint(6)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| month_year            | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date_cns              | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Find the indexes for the previous table:

```
+--------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name               | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| cns_dvc      |          0 | dvc                    |            1 | dvc          | A         |       33847 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| cns_dvc      |          0 | dvc                    |            2 | date_str     | A         |     4264740 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| cns_dvc      |          0 | dvc                    |            3 | pg_avg       | A         |     4264740 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| cns_dvc      |          0 | uidx_dvc_date_cns      |            1 | dvc          | A         |        7084 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| cns_dvc      |          0 | uidx_dvc_date_cns      |            2 | date_cns     | A         |     4264740 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| cns_dvc      |          1 | month                  |            1 | month        | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| cns_dvc      |          1 | year                   |            1 | year         | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

When I am trying to add some partitions I get the following error:

```
ALTER TABLE cns_dvc PARTITION BY RANGE(YEAR(date_cns))( PARTITION p2020 VALUES LESS THAN(2021), PARTITION p2021 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE );
ERROR 1503 (HY000): A UNIQUE INDEX must include all columns in the table's partitioning function
```

Should I add an unique index only on the date_cns column? If so, that column could not be unique.
Perhaps, the partition type is not the right one?

Edit:
Show CREATE TABLE cns_dvc;

```
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table        | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| cns_dvc      | CREATE TABLE `cns_dvc` (
  `id_dvc` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `dvc` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `zone` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_str` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_prs` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `no_week` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `day` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `pg_avg` decimal(6,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i_spd_avg` decimal(15,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `o_spd_avg` decimal(15,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` decimal(15,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `month` decimal(15,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `month_year` decimal(15,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_cns` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `dvc` (`dvc`,`date_str`,`pg_avg`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `uidx_dvc_date_cns` (`dvc`,`date_cns`),
  KEY `month` (`month`),
  KEY `year` (`year`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Show CREATE TABLE for your table.

Comment: And study [RANGE COLUMNS partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-columns-range.html).

Comment: Added the show create table for my table and I am having the same issue when I try to alter my table with a new partition based on range columns;

Comment: I have investigated a little... and I cannot find the way for partitioning the table which have 2 unique indices. Server needs all columns present in unique index to be included into partitioning expression (no skipped fields) and backward (no excess fields) - which is impossible when 2 different indices exists.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and you're right. It's due to unique indexes. After removing those indexes, I have been able to create partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I had done was to create a duplicate table without indexes. I have executed the same SQL for partition creation did work (ALTER TABLE cns_dvc PARTITION BY etc.).

All columns defined in unique indexes of the table should be part of partition definition which means those 4 columns in this case: dvc, date_str, pg_avg, date_cns

I guess it will be easier for me to create again the table with partition. Then adding uniques indexes on the partition.

Answer (score 0):

- You have `UNIQUE` keys, but each has at least one `NULLable` column.  So none can be promoted to `PRIMARY KEY`.
- Every table should have a PK.  In your case, an hidden (inaccessible) PK will be generated for you.
- Why have two `UNIQUE` keys?  That is often a schema design error.
- Don't partition a table unless it has at least a million rows.
- Don't expect performance improvement by simply partitioning.
- Do use partitioning if you need to delete "old" data; is that what you are doing?
- "A UNIQUE INDEX must include all columns in the table's partitioning function" is an absolute requirement.  (Maybe some year there will be "global" unique keys.)
- You have "month" in several columns, of multiple datatypes; please explain.  Normally, it is best to clean up dates/datetimes *during input*, and use `DATE`, `DATETIME`, and/or `TIMESTAMP`, not `VARCHAR`.  And I have never heard of using `DECIMAL`!?
- It is *usually* better to pick apart a `DATE` in a `SELECT` than to have the parts spread across column.
- Let's see the main `SELECTs`; we can advise on how to provide optimal indexing for a partitioned and a non-partitioned table.